# List Sales Totals for all Sales Regions via the Territories table using 4 joins

Tags: c#, sql, northwind

I am trying to list sales totals for all regions using 4 joins via the Territories table in the Northwind database and so far have identified some of the tables I need however I am still weak on joins so I am not entirely sure how to run this query. So far I have done this. Now I am not sure if this is right or what joins should be done next any advice will help. I am using visual studio to run these quires.

```
SELECT SUM(od.Quantity * od.UnitPrice) total_sales FROM [Order Details] od
INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.orderID = od.orderID
```

Comment: Start by using SQL Sever Management Studio and run query in SSMS before trying in c#.  The error message in SSMS are much better than in VS and will help correct the errors.

Comment: from what I see in northwind db, there is no distinct criteria to decide, which territory the order belong to